# How to handle non-view-altering actions in Flux & React.js

Tags: javascript, scroll, reactjs, action, reactjs-flux

In Flux every action should be handled by the dispatcher.

What about an action that doesn't alter the view or the markup, such as "scroll this element into view"? What is the "Flux-way" of handling such a scenario? To by-pass the dispatcher? Or to handle it in the dispatcher without involving the stores or the components?

Comment: "every action should be handled by the dispatcher" is not true.

Comment: @Khnle-Kevin Very good point! I changed the question to read "Flux" instead of "React.js". That is much more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flux is really more about application state management, and is not at all about the details of what components are rendered in the view.  That's the domain of React.  Flux simply assumes you have some kind of reactive view layer -- usually that's React.

Application state is not the same as component state.  Application state is something that needs to be known in multiple components.  For component state, React's `this.state` is perfectly adequate.  An input component is a good example of something that might need this.

So in your case, if only one component needs to know the scroll position, there may not be a good case for moving that state to a Flux Store.  But as soon as that needs to be known in multiple components -- especially components in different branches of the tree -- you probably want that state being managed in a Store.

The other issue your question raises is the role of Flux Actions.  A Flux application always uses Actions as the origin of the data flow.  There are a lot of good reasons for doing this: stable application state, keeping the app resilient to new features, keeping it easy to reason about, undo history, reconstitution of application state, stateless view components, etc.

Occasionally people want to write as little code as possible and they use a callback passed between components to change `this.state` in the parent component instead of dispatching a new action to go through the Flux data flow.  I find this to be mixing the view and state management layers of an application, and while expedient, this can lead to a lot of headache.  It isn't very flexible in the long run, because now the state is coupled to these few components.  Building up a Flux data flow from the start is much simpler in the long run, and much more resilient to new features.  That said, it also requires more investment in code up front.

Answer (score 3):

If your app doesn't need to know about scrolling (seems rare that it would), there's no need to fire an action. Since Flux is really there to handle data flow (and subsequent changes based on that data flow), it doesn't need to know about every action that occurs.