# Unsure of the semantics of React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm quite new to react and trying to wrap my head around the semantics.

I am building a map based application and the primary parts of the site are the map, the navbar and a search menu which pops up over the map and allows you to select a search which is populated from an ajax request.

**Here are some questions which come to mind:**

Where should I complete my ajax requests, should that all be contained in the map component? If so, how do I pass the parameters for the request, if the answer is pass it to a function in map then how do I call the function from inside my search menu component?

**My app is currently organised like so:**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  toggleSearchMenu() {
    this.refs.searchMenu.toggleVisible();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pure-g">
        <Nav>
          <NavButton onClick={() => this.toggleSearchMenu()}>Searches</NavButton>
        </Nav>
        <Map lat="53.15" lng="-0.5" zoom="9" />
        <SearchMenu ref="searchMenu" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have resulted to showing and hiding the menu from a function within my app component which doesn't feel right somehow?

Answer (score 3):

As you know, React is only responsible for rendering the views, but it doesn't define how to structure the actual logic of your app. Facebook suggests to use the Flux architecture for that. This site and video should get you on the right track: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/05/06/flux.html

Basically, you want all actions to enter the same "pipeline", no matter where they come from. Logic and some state is kept in "stores" (sort of a hybrid between a Model and a Controller) and finally components listen to changes in those stores and then re-render themselves.

Comment: Thanks Johannes, that does sound useful for the mapping side. How about the displaying of the menu on nav button click? I don't want to hardcode this, I want any button to be able to show any menu (reusable). Or is that something that flux would cover?

Comment: I asked a somewhat similar question a while ago and got an answer from Bill Fisher (one of the creators of React/Flux): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057600/how-to-handle-non-view-altering-actions-in-flux-react-js

Comment: So you want to ask yourself: Is an action or the data I get back from an AJAX call changing the *state* of my app?  Or is an action simply hiding/showing something volatile like a tooltip or a context menu? Then it could be considered part of the component and not something that changes the state of the app.